# packaging & Universal installer

Tags: deployment, installation, packaging, setup-deployment

I am building a solution that runs on top of:

- PHP
- Apache
- PostgreSQL
- Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle)

I am indeed looking for packaging possibilities as I want to bundle the whole solution including the required runtime (web server, db server, etl server) to ease it's installation, configuration and deployment.

Can you please point me to the possibilities that are available to me giving that my requirements toward the packaging system/methodology are:

- Easy to use (at some extent)
- Eases configuration
- Cross platform (preferably, but two separate proposals for Windows & *nix are welcome)
- Easy to maintain
- Easy to use for patching purposes

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not enough detail for a full answer, but as a starting point you could customise an existing [L/W/M]AMP installer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

Comment: I gave very high level details indeed but I don't mind having a high level answer neither :). I have thought about your proposal but I would rather create my package by myself instead of hack an existing one and like get mysql out of it...etc. What other details should I append to get you interested? Thankx !!

Comment: Ah, I meant that my response was just a comment and not detailed enough to be a real answer. :)

I still suspect that if you are essentially building a wrapper which installs and configures PHP, Apache, DB server etc., then it'd be worth checking out existing projects with similar goals.

Comment: The existing ones target a development environement that can be quickly set up. I want a packaging that will be used to deploy to production directly at customer's site. I am thinking of making a python script for example that does it all together